emit changes from vue1 to a table of a q-tab-panel in vue2
i am trying to emit changes from my serialnumberdialog.vue to a table of a q-tab-panel in my viewdetails.vue.
please help me get the expected outcome. i already tried almost everything and asked for help using chatgpt but i can't seem to find the right solution. also, sometimes the output is just a blank white screen and errors in the console so i am having a hard time.
this is my serialnumberdialog code:
<template>
  <transition appear enter-active-class="animated fadeIn" leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" :duration="3000">
    <div class="template-content">
      <div class="q-px-lg q-pt-lg gt-xs">
        <!-- HEADER START -->
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center q-pt-md">
          <div class="flex items-center">
            <h5 class="text-26 text-bold q-my-none q-ml-md" style="font-size: 26px">Select Serial Number</h5>
          </div>
          <q-btn
    @click="handleSaveSerialNumber"
    unelevated
    rounded
    label="Save"
    class="saveserial no-uppercase-saveserial"
    style="border-style: hidden; width: 160px; height: 38px; background-color: #d48806; color: white"
  />
        </div>
        <h5 class="text-semibold q-my-none" style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 16px">You have 3 existing serial numbers. Kindly assign it to the respective variant and store.</h5>
        <!-- HEADER END -->

        <div class="flex items-center">
          <!-- STORE BUTTON START -->
          <div class="q-pa-md">
            <transition appear enter-active-class="animated fadeIn" leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" :duration="2000">
              <q-btn-dropdown
                unelevated
                rounded
                :style="{ border: '1px solid #d48806', width: '190px', height: '31px' }"
                color="white"
                text-color="black"
                class="no-uppercase"
              >
                <template v-slot:label>
                  <div style="flex: 1; text-align: left; font-size: 14px">{{ selectedStore ? selectedStore : 'Select Store' }}</div>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:icon-right>
                  <q-icon name="arrow_drop_down" color="#869AB2" />
                </template>
                <q-list>
                  <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="onStoreClick('Store 1')">
                    <q-item-section>
                      <q-item-label>Store 1</q-item-label>
                    </q-item-section>
                  </q-item>
                  <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="onStoreClick('Store 2')">
                    <q-item-section>
                      <q-item-label>Store 2</q-item-label>
                    </q-item-section>
                  </q-item>
                  <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="onStoreClick('Store 3')">
                    <q-item-section>
                      <q-item-label>Store 3</q-item-label>
                    </q-item-section>
                  </q-item>
                </q-list>
              </q-btn-dropdown>
            </transition>
          </div>
          <!-- STORE BUTTON END -->

          <!-- PAGINATION START -->
          <div class="im-pagination-container flex justify-center items-center" style="height: 36px; margin-left: auto; font-size: 15px; width: 132px;">
            <div class="q-pagination row no-wrap items-center pagination" :max="maxPages" input="v-model='current'" aria-disabled="false" role="navigation">
              <div class="q-pagination__content row no-wrap items-center">
                <button class="q-btn q-btn-item non-selectable no-outline q-btn--flat q-btn--rounded text-grey-8"
                  tabindex="-1" type="button" @click="prevPage" :disabled="isFirstPage" aria-label="Previous"
                  style="font-size: 8px; padding: 3px 2px; width: 29px; height: 28px;">
                  <span class="q-focus-helper"></span>
                  <span class="q-btn__content text-center col items-center q-anchor--skip justify-center row">
                    <i class="q-icon notranslate material-icons" aria-hidden="true" role="img">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
                  </span>
                </button>
                <div class="q-pagination__middle row justify-center">
                  <q-btn v-for="page in pages" :key="page" @click="setPage(page)" :label="page" :flat="current !== page" :color="current === page ? 'grey-8' : 'grey-2'" style="font-size: 10px; padding: 3px 2px; min-width: 2em; height: 31px;" />
                </div>
                <button class="q-btn q-btn-item non-selectable no-outline q-btn--flat q-btn--rectangle text-grey-8"
                  tabindex="0" type="button" @click="nextPage" :disabled="isLastPage" aria-label="Next"
                  style="font-size: 8px; padding: 3px 2px; width: 29px; height: 28px;">
                  <span class="q-focus-helper"></span>
                  <span class="q-btn__content text-center col items-center q-anchor--skip justify-center row">
                    <i class="q-icon notranslate material-icons" aria-hidden="true" role="img">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="im-pagination-select-input text-no-wrap" style="height: 31px;">
              <label class="q-field row no-wrap items-start q-field--outlined q-select q-field--auto-height q-select--without-input q-select--without-chips q-select--single q-field--rounded q-field--float q-field--dense im-input-field" style="height: 31px;">
                <div class="q-field__inner relative-position col self-stretch">
                  <div class="q-field__control relative-position row no-wrap" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="q-field__control-container col relative-position row no-wrap q-anchor--skip">
                      <div class="q-field__native row items-center">
                        <span>{{ current }} / {{ maxPages }}</span>
                        <input class="q-select__focus-target" readonly tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-expanded="false">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="q-field__append q-field__marginal row no-wrap items-center q-anchor--skip">
                      <i class="q-icon notranslate material-icons q-select__dropdown-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">arrow_drop_down</i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- PAGINATION END -->
        </div>

        <!-- Store Preview/Table -->
      <div v-if="!selectedStore" class="store-preview flex justify-center items-center">
        <span class="text-24">No preview available. Please select store.</span>
      </div>
      <div v-else class="q-table__container q-table--horizontal-separator column no-wrap q-table__card q-table--flat q-table--no-wrap im-table">
        <div class="q-table__middle scroll">
          <div class="q-table-container" style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <table class="q-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-left" style="width: 50%;">Variant</th>
                  <th class="text-left" style="width: 50%;">Serial Number</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="text-left text-14" style="height: 50px !important;" v-for="(variant, index) in variants" :key="index">
                  <td style="height: 50px;">{{ variant }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <SerialNumberDropdown
                      :serialNumbers="serialNumbers"
                      :selectedSerialNumbers="selectedSerialNumbersMap[selectedStore]?.[index] || []"
                      :onSerialSelect="onSerialSelect"
                      :serialNumberId="index.toString()"
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="q-table__bottom row items-center q-table__bottom--nodata">
          <i class="q-icon notranslate material-icons q-table__bottom-nodata-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">warning</i>
          No data available
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import SerialNumberDropdown from './SerialNumberDropdown.vue';
import { QBtn, QBtnDropdown, QIcon, QItem, QItemSection, QList } from 'quasar';

export default {
  name: 'SerialNumberDialog',
  emits: ['save-serial-number', 'update-serial-numbers'], // Declare the events

  components: {
    QBtn,
    QBtnDropdown,
    QIcon,
    QItem,
    QItemSection,
    QList,
    SerialNumberDropdown,
  },

  setup() {
    const current = ref(1);
    const maxPages = ref(5);
    const selectedStore = ref(null);
    const serialNumbers = ref(['147852AHGSDGDSDA', '3587ADEHJSGDKWG', '985799SAKHSAHS666']);
    const selectedSerialNumbersMap = ref({
      'Store 1': Array.from({ length: 9 }, () => []),
      'Store 2': Array.from({ length: 9 }, () => []),
      'Store 3': Array.from({ length: 9 }, () => [])
    });
    const variants = ref(['Black, Small', 'Black, Medium', 'Black, Large', 'Beige, Small', 'Beige, Medium', 'Beige, Large', 'White, Small', 'White, Medium', 'White, Large']);

    const pages = computed(() => Array.from({ length: maxPages.value }, (_, i) => i + 1));
    const isFirstPage = computed(() => current.value === 1);
    const isLastPage = computed(() => current.value === maxPages.value);

    const prevPage = () => { if (!isFirstPage.value) current.value -= 1; };
    const nextPage = () => { if (!isLastPage.value) current.value += 1; };
    const setPage = (page) => { current.value = page; };
    const onStoreClick = (store) => { selectedStore.value = store; };

    const onSerialSelect = (serialNumberId, serialNumber) => {
      const store = selectedStore.value;
      if (!store) return;

      const selectedSerials = selectedSerialNumbersMap.value[store][serialNumberId];
      const index = selectedSerials.indexOf(serialNumber);
      if (index > -1) {
        selectedSerials.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        selectedSerials.push(serialNumber);
      }

      // Emit the event with the updated data
      this.$emit('update-serial-numbers', selectedSerialNumbersMap.value);
    };

    return {
      current,
      maxPages,
      pages,
      isFirstPage,
      isLastPage,
      prevPage,
      nextPage,
      setPage,
      onStoreClick,
      onSerialSelect,
      selectedStore,
      serialNumbers,
      selectedSerialNumbersMap,
      variants,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleSaveSerialNumber() {
      const serialData = (this.selectedSerialNumbersMap[this.selectedStore] || []).map((serialNumbers, index) => ({
        serialNumber: serialNumbers.join(', '),
        variant: this.variants[index],
        store: this.selectedStore,
      }));

      // Emit save event with serial number data
      this.$emit('save-serial-number', serialData);

      this.$router.go(-1);
    },
  },
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.no-uppercase {
  text-transform: none !important;
}

.no-uppercase-saveserial {
  text-transform: none !important;
}

.im-pagination-container {
  border-radius: 19px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-left.text-14 {
  height: 50px !important;
}

.q-pa-md {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.q-table-container {
  width: 979px;
  height: 506px;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>

this is my viewdetails.vue:
<q-tab-panel name="serial-number" class="q-px-none" v-if="form && !form.enable_serial_number">
        <div class="flex justify-between q-px-xs q-mt-xs">
          <div class="flex justify-start items-center">
            <div class="text-14">Store:</div>
            <q-select
              borderless
              v-model="store"
              :label="store !== null ? '' : 'Select Store'"
              :options="storeOption"
              class="im-select-field im-border-radius-50 height-31 min-width-190 im-border-accent-0 text-center text-15 q-ma-md"
              popup-content-class="im-option-style-light"
            />
            <div class="text-14">Status:</div>
            <q-select
              borderless
              v-model="status"
              :label="status !== null ? '' : 'Available'"
              :options="statusOption"
              class="im-select-field im-border-radius-50 height-31 min-width-190 im-border-accent-0 text-center text-15 q-ma-md"
              popup-content-class="im-option-style-light"
            />
            <div class="text-14">Variant</div>
            <q-select
              borderless
              v-model="variant"
              :label="variant !== null ? '' : 'All'"
              :options="variantOption"
              class="im-select-field im-border-radius-50 height-31 min-width-190 im-border-accent-0 text-center text-15 q-ma-md"
              popup-content-class="im-option-style-light"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="flex justify-start items-center">
            <div class="text-14 q-mr-md">Serial Number:</div>
            <Filters
              dynamicHeight="34"
              :searchVisible="true"
              :filterDateVisible="false"
              :labelVisible="false"
              pathEndPoint="projects"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- If store is null -->
        <div v-if="!store" class="store-preview flex justify-center items-center">
          <!-- Then render no preview available -->
          <span class="text-24">No preview available. Please select store.</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Else render the table -->

        <q-table
          v-else
          :rows="serialRows"
          :columns="serialColumns"
          row-key="serialNumbers"
          class="im-table"
          flat
        />

        <ul>
      <li v-for="(serialNumbers, index) in serialNumbers" :key="index">
        {{ serialNumbers }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</q-tab-panel>

and this is my viewdetails.js:
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Filters from '../../../components/Filters.vue';
import Pagination from '../../../components/Pagination.vue';
import SerialNumberDialog from '../SerialNumberDialog.vue';
import { ProductDetails } from '../../../composables/Products';
import AddProduct from '../AddProduct.vue';
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  props: {
    serialNumbers: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  components: {
    Filters,
    Pagination,
    AddProduct,
    SerialNumberDialog,
  },

  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const route = useRoute();

     // Initialize the form object to avoid undefined issues
     const form = ref({
      enable_batch_tracking: false,
      enable_serial_number: false,
    });

    // Define state using Composition API
    const tab = ref('product-details');
    const serialRows = ref([]); // Ensure this is reactive
    const serialColumns = [
      { name: 'serialNumber', label: 'Serial Number', align: 'left', field: 'serialNumber' },
      { name: 'rfid', label: 'RFID', align: 'left', field: 'rfid'},
      { name: 'variant', label: 'Variant', align: 'center', field: 'variant' },
      { name: 'statusOption', label: 'Status', align: 'right', field: 'statusOption' },
      { name: 'date', label: 'Date Modified', align: 'right', field: 'date' },
    ];

    // For select option
    const store = ref(null);
    const storeOption = ref(['Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3']);
    const status = ref(null);
    const statusOption = ref(['Available', 'Unavailable']);
    const variant = ref(null);
    const variantOption = ref([
      'All',
      'Black, Small',
      'Black, Medium',
      'Black, Large',
      'Beige, Small',
      'Beige, Medium',
      'Beige, Large',
      'White, Small',
      'White, Medium',
      'White, Large',
    ]);

    // For batch table
    const batchRows = ref([]);
    const batchColumns = [
      { name: 'batchNumber', align: 'left', label: 'Batch Number', field: 'batchNumber' },
      { name: 'rfid', align: 'left', label: 'RFID', field: 'rfid' },
      { name: 'expiryDate', align: 'left', label: 'Expiry Date', field: 'expiryDate' },
      { name: 'originalStock', align: 'left', label: 'Original Stock', field: 'originalStock' },
      { name: 'remainingStock', align: 'left', label: 'Remaining Stock', field: 'remainingStock' },
    ];

    const editProduct = () => {
      router.push({
        name: 'add-products',
        params: {
          id: route.params.id,
        },
      });
    };

    return {
      tab,
      form,
      serialRows, // Reactive array to store serial numbers
      serialColumns,
      batchRows,
      batchColumns,
      store,
      storeOption,
      status,
      statusOption,
      variant,
      variantOption,
      ProductDetails,
      editProduct,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateSerialRows(serialData) {
      // Update the serialRows data here
      this.serialRows = serialData;
    },

    updateSerialNumbers(updatedSerialNumbersMap) {
      this.selectedSerialNumbersMap = updatedSerialNumbersMap;

      // Now you can derive the `serialRows` array from `selectedSerialNumbersMap`
      this.serialRows = [];
      for (const store in updatedSerialNumbersMap) {
        if (updatedSerialNumbersMap.hasOwnProperty(store)) {
          updatedSerialNumbersMap[store].forEach((serialNumbers, variantIndex) => {
            this.serialRows.push({
              variant: this.variantOption[variantIndex + 1], // Adjust the index based on your variant options
              serialNumber: serialNumbers.join(', '),
              store: store,
            });
          });
        }
      }
    },
  },
};


To emit events globally in Vue or generally in JS you need a simple EventBus like:
// eventBus.js
import Vue from 'vue';

export const EventBus = new Vue();

Then in your components you can subscribe to events in this event bus on creation or at mounting and fire events from everywhere.
You also may consider to use a store in your app. Your templates look too busy and using a store like Pinia you may simplify your templates and even may not need those "special" events as the data will be immediately available in both views/templates.
What to ask ChatGPT in your case ;-)

how to emit events globally in vue2?


how to add a store state like Pinia in vue2

and GPT4o gives a pretty good answer with code etc.
Hope that helps.
